# How to get saved registers of a process in Linux (ARM Architecture)

Tags: linux, arm

I'm writing a program that parses all tasks running on linux, starting from init_task for each task i read it's task_struct structure which allows me to get it's PID, State, Oncpu..

However i also need to find the saved registers of that task, especially registers R0 to R10, IP, SP, FP and PC

Also in task_struct I found a pointer to a structure called cpu_context which holds registers R4 to PC

So the problem is that I don't know how to get registers R0 to R3
I tried to manually parse the stack of the task but i haven't found any relevant values

so here are my questions:

-where in the stack(or in an other location in memory) are saved the registers of a task that is not running?

-Can I trust the values of the registers R4 to PC found in the structure cpu_context?

I'm using  a board containing an ARM Cortex A9 MPCore processor(2 cores), linked with the host PC with a JTAG Link

Linux Kernel 2.6.35.7+ is running on the board(of course this kernel was compiled for the ARM architecture)

On the Host PC i'm using OPENOCD and GDB for the debug.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

It depends on which set of registers you are interested in.

If you are interested in the user mode state, take a look on how `ptrace` does it. From a quick peek at the source code, `task_pt_regs(task)` is where you should look. Apparently, they are near the top of the kernel stack for the task (take a look at `vector_swi` for instance; it has a `stmia   sp, {r0 - r12}` near its beginning, followed by a store of `sp` and `lr`).

If you are interested in the kernel mode state, it is saved by `__switch_to` into `task->cpu_context` (`TI_CPU_SAVE` is the offset of `cpu_context` within the `struct thread_info`). As another answer already noted, it doesn't save r0-r3 because it doesn't have to; the caller of `switch_to` assumes they will be clobbered by `__switch_to`, so their values don't matter.

Answer (score 1):

`cpu_context` contains the value of registers when __switch_to is called, caller saved registers are not stored.

If you want the value of registers upon entry to an interrupt or system call you need to look elsewhere.